# Proper use of threads Win32

Tags: c++, multithreading

I just learning about Win32 programming and had a question about threading. Suppose I have the example below, I want to know if the PrintStuff() function being called inside the for-loop runs on the new thread that was created or does it run on the main thread? Thanks.

```
    HANDLE hThrd;
    DWORD WINAPI PrintStuff() {
        OutputDebugString("printing stuff");
        return 0;
    }
    int WINAPI WinMain(...) {
        ...
        hThrd = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)PrintStuff, NULL, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &id)
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            PrintStuff();
        }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: The PrintStuff() in your for loop runs in the original thread.  PrintStuff() will also run in your new hread ... if/when you ever start that new thread (after creating it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to think that `CreateThread` somehow "marks" a function to be run in another thread, so that each time it is called it's run in another thread. It's not like that. `CreateThread`, as the name implies, just creates a new thread whose entry point is the function you specified. All the instructions that follow the call are still running in the same thread as before, while the function you specified will be called once in a separate thread a few moments after calling `CreateThread`.

Incidentally, if you are going to use any function from the standard library on newly created threads you should not use directly `CreateThread`, use instead `_beginthread`.

---

I see now that you are specifying the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag; thus, the new thread will never run unless you call `ResumeThread` on it.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to work out which thread is running the function.

### 1. Getting the current thread ID

[`GetCurrentThreadId()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183(v=vs.85).aspx) can be used with the Windows API.

There are a number of other ways in C++. The C++ standard library also provides [`std::this_thread::get_id()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/get_id) in `#include <thread>` which can be used to get an ID to compare in a platform independent way.

Using the thread ID, you can simply check the thread ID at the start of WinMain and store the main thread's ID in a global variable, which you can use in PrintStuff.

Please note that the set of IDs returned by standard library get_id() is different from GetCurrentThreadId(), so you will need to pick one.

### 2. Using a thread local variable.

On a windows platform with Visual Studio, you can use `__declspec(thread)`. If you have C++14 (available with Visual Studio 2015), you can use `thread_local`.

Using a thread local variable, you can easily work out if the main thread is running the function.

```
__declspec(thread) bool isMainThread = false;
HANDLE hThrd;
DWORD WINAPI PrintStuff() {
    OutputDebugString("printing stuff");
    // check isMainThread here
    return 0;
}
int WINAPI WinMain(...) {
    isMainThread = true;
    ...
    hThrd = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)PrintStuff, NULL, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &id)
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        PrintStuff();
    }
    ...
}
```

A thread local variable can be used to store a thread name, rather than just printing a thread ID which is not always easy to interpret.

### 3. Pass an argument to the function, or use a wrapper function

If you just want to print something differently, you can use a wrapper function when you create a new thread, and get this function to pass an argument to your PrintStuff function. If you don't want to pass an argument to PrintStuff to do something different, you can also use a wrapper function to set a thread local variable. This is where you can give the thread a name.

Answer (score 0):

you can print threadId to see what thread is used.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183(v=vs.85).aspx

If you want to check if it is print in the main thread, you can get the main threadId used above function and compare it with the threadId in PrintStuff.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**GetCurrentThreadId()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from your function to know which thread is currently executing it.

```
DWORD WINAPI PrintStuff() {
    DWORD idThread = GetCurrentThreadId();
    printf("Thread ID: %i.\n", idThread);
}
```